# Relational Database - iOS - Parse - Cross reference favorited postings vs all postings

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, relational-database

I have a database with a table of listings (of real estate for example) and a table of users. Users can favorite listings. I have to show all listings on a page and show on the listing whether or not they are favorited by the current user. In general, what's the best way to do this.

I realize this is a general question. This is for iOS development. I am pulling all the listings right now and am just adding the functionality of favorited listings. On the iOS end, I am creating an array of local Listing objects and displaying them in a tableView. Now I want to be able mark those Listings favorited or not depending on if they are marked favorited as a relation through the user.

Anyone have a simple basic explanation of how to do something like this?

Right now, I already have the array of listings that I am showing.
Now I am thinking, where I am already querying the listings, I should also query the relation and get an array of postings that are favorited by the user.

Now, as I call `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (for each cell), I can loop through the array of favorited listings and see if that posting is in there (yielding an N^2 algorithm).

Anyone see a better way to be dealing with something like this?

Answer (score 0):

You can take your array of liked listings and make a dictionary out of it. It will be O(1) to check if a listing is liked or not.

```
var likedListings = [PFObject]()
var hash = [String: Bool]()

for listing in likedListings {
    hash[listing.objectId!] = true
}

var aListing = PFObject() // say that it is the listing in cellForRowAtIndexPath
if let val = hash[aListing.objectId!] {
    if val == true {
        // aListing is liked
    }
}
```

You can see a good example of like feature in Parse's example app [Anypic](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Anypic/blob/master/Anypic-iOS/Anypic/PAPCache.m#L34). They use `NSCache` to keep some attributes (likers, commenters, likedByCurrentUser, etc) for each photo. The idea is the same as above.

Comment: I will give this a try when I get back around to this code. This looks like what I needed though.